# How to get Pointer to Index in QTreeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a QTreeWidget, and populated it with struct data (myObj.name, myObj.DOB, myObj.age, etc).

When I select on an item in the widget, I need to grab the pointer data associated with that selection to display it elsewhere.

I create the list with pointers, I just need to figure out how to in turn retrieve those pointers when I select on the list.

Comment: You mean, the "myObj" pointer

Comment: yes, the myObj pointer. That is what has all of the struct data assigned to it, and it is this data that I need to retreive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to achieve what I needed by using QMap.

```
QMap<QTreeWidgetItem*, myObject*> myMap_container;//declared in .h
```

And then in my cpp:

```
    void MainWindow::on_myTree_itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column){
       myObject* rowData = myMap_container[item];
}
```

From there I was able to access the entirety of my struct data which has been assigned like so:

```
cout << rowData.Name << endl;
cout << rowData.Age << endl;
cout << rowData.SSN<< endl;
cout << rowData.FavColor<< endl;
```

Comment: Now I understood more. Instead of creating additional map, did you try assigning the pointer any column value and make the column hidden. I do not know if it is feasible or not. just an idea..

Answer (score 0):

To access the data within your QTreeWidget (or rather the predefined tree model that comes for free with QTreeWidget), you can utilise one of the signals that QTreeWidget emits upon user interaction. i.e. clicked(QModelIndex).

The QTreeWidget documentation lists all of the signals available: (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#details)

For example:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(print_item(QModelIndex)));
```

Where 'this' is of type QTreeWidget.  (I have populated a number of QString items into my tree structure),

With the above connected Signal and Slot, a click on one of my tree items results in the following method being executed,

```
void MainWindow::print_item(QModelIndex index){

    qDebug()<<"Item :"<<index.data().toString();
}
```

As you can see the parameter that the 'clicked' signal passes is a QModelIndex which I then use in my above method to access the data within my tree item.

Comment: Very useful, thank you. However, I'm not sure how to access the struct data from this point.

I need something like this to work:
`selPointer = index.data();
selPointer.age = 40;

Answer (score 0):

As I am seeing tree widget here and not Abstract Model,I guess you are using columns in your widget. For example your node has three columns :name( 0 column), DOB ( 1 column) and age (2 column).

If that is the case, the simple way is:

```
QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> QlistTreeWId = YourTree->selectedItems();
```

Check for the list size, if size exists, then

```
yourObject.name = QlistTreeWId [0].text(0); //name column.
yourObject.DOB= QlistTreeWId [0].text(1); //DOB column.
yourObject.age= QlistTreeWId [0].text(2); //Age column.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I need is the pointer stored at a given index.  YourObject* needs to be returned because it contains way more data than just 3 columns worth. I'm only displaying 3 columns as a brief overview. I then allow the user to scope down into the data for more information.  This widget is the springboard into the data, but as the list populates, I need to be able to access the pointers for each row.